# How to force the user to write a password before accessing a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I am working on a web development project and I am asked to force users to fill in the password field from the homepage form before granting them access to the main webpage. However, even if I put the "required" tag in the password input field, I get the opposite behaviour. The webpage gives access to the user when no password is written and when a password is written, it doesn't. It would be very helpful if someone could help with this issue. I am leaving here the code for the input form and also the function that is supposed to provide this behaviour.

----HTML code for form (focus on the second input, with id="form-psw"----

```html
<div id="homepage-form">
  <form id="homepage-data-form" class="form-container">
    <h1 id="homepage-form-heading">Login</h1>

    <label for="email" class="form-label bold">Email</label>
    <input id="form-email" type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

    <label for="psw" class="bold">Password</label>
    <input id="form-psw" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
  </form>
</div>
```

-----JS code to control the explained behaviour------

```js
function checkCookie() {
  var cname = document.getElementById("form-email").value;
  var user = getCookie(cname);
  if (user == "") {
    alert("Sorry, the provided email is not registered. Click on the Register option to get your account.");
  } else {
    window.location.href = "main.html";
  }
}
```

Comment: Where and how in your JS is the `checkCookie` function called?

Comment: This may not work if you have a click event listener on the button. Since I see no "action" attribute, my guess is the click event listener is bypassing the required tag. Here's a JS Fiddle showing this in action: https://jsfiddle.net/dmru0b8y/1/

Please confirm this is the case with your code. If it is, you can solve it with a simple if statement that checks if password is empty.

Comment: `
            <button type="submit" class="btn bold" onclick="checkCookie()">Login</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn register bold" onclick="">Register</button>
          </form>   
        <button onclick="createStudentsCookies()"> Accept cookies</button>
        </div> `

Comment: Add that to your question, not here in the comments.

Comment: When the user presses the Login button, it checks whether a cookie is stored.

Comment: See this JS Fiddle I modified. As you can see, it doesn't care if the field is filled in when executing the code as you're telling the code to run when clicked. https://jsfiddle.net/dmru0b8y/5/

You'll need to write some custom code as I described in my comment above to fix the problem.

Comment: I would suggest to using a submit action (button, link with type=submit). Then, choosing if you want to use the default behaviour for handling the form, or using you own (through action or onsubmit form attributes, or even in the JS file)

Comment: @EmielZuurbier We are already checking the password length so that it isn't empty by means of the following condition, but it still doesn't work: `else if(user!="" && document.getElementById("form-psw").value.length>0) {
        window.location.href = "main.html";
    }`

Comment: @Truancito_2000 - You need to modify this post with ALL RELEVANT code if you want help. You're sending in bits and pieces and creating confusion while also wasting the time of people trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Having a webpage password-protected is never a smart idea. This is because there are too many exploits. The best way to do such a thing would be doing it with a .htaccess file. And btw, the required attribute for an input field only works if you put it in a form tag

Comment: Agree - this could be easily bypassed in seconds by anyone who can read JavaScript code. Sounds to me like OP is working on a project for a class. Hopefully this isn't anything deployed to the real world 

Comment: Your first sentence is missing the critical phrase "*by client-side javascript*"

Comment: The problem is that there is no way to achieve this with client-sided javascript, nor would it be with server-sided js. Javascript has too many ways around it to actually force a password.